# Stopping Multiple Tasks

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms, task

I'm using the following method to create new Tasks and do long time taking operations in background.If a certain condition is met,I need to completely stop all the tasks and show the user a message.

```
dowork()
{

    mylist = new List<DataModel.CheckData>();
    int index = 0;
    foreach (var line in mylist)
    {
        mylist.Add(new DataModel.CheckData() { RawLine = line, data = line,FileName=virtualfilelist[index].ToString() });
        index++;
    }

    BlockingCollection<DataModel.CheckData> ujobs = new BlockingCollection<DataModel.CheckData>();
    timerRefreshUi.Start();

    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        _dtRows.Clear();
        uiQueue.Clear();
        uiQueueBad.Clear();
        uiQueueGood.Clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < mylist.Count; i++)
        {
             AddResultRow(mylist[i].data, "Waiting...",mylist[i].FileName, Color.White);
             ujobs.TryAdd(new DataModel.CheckData() { RowId = i, data = mylist[i].data }, 1000);

         }
         List<Task> openCheckTasks = new List<Task>();

         while (ujobs.Count > 0)
         {
             while (openCheckTasks.Where(task => task.Status == TaskStatus.Running).ToList().Count >= threadcount)
              System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250);

              Task t = new Task(new Action(() =>
              {

              }));

              openCheckTasks.Add(t);
              t.Start();
         }
         Task.WaitAll(openCheckTasks.ToArray());

    }).ContinueWith(task => {
        _benchmark.Stop();
        this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {

        }));

    });

}
```

I have tried using `Cancellation Token` and `break` in the while loop.But it is not working properly.Please advice the best way to stop all the threads.I have very little experience with Multiple Thread Programming.

Comment: There is a nice answer there. Just keep in mind that fundamentally threads do NOT have a fullproof way to stop then. Neither in .net nor in java. All "answers" are hacks to get around this behavior. If (1) your background-tasks are longer than (say) 10secs, and (2) you need to stop them deterministically and (3) at any given time you wont have like thousands of such tasks running, consider `process` over thread.

Comment: Why are you trying to limit the number of tasks created? TPL already does a good job of scheduling and you're limited to the number of cores on your PC as to how many tasks can be processed simultaneously. The `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250);` inside a loop isn't a very useful pattern.

Comment: You're essentially trying to process your items with a limited degree of parallelism. .NET already has tools for that (and they support cooperative cancellation too): `Parallel.ForEach` and/or TPL Dataflow.

Comment: `CancellationToken` is your friend - check MSDN for more information, bud.

Comment: Your methods which uses tasks **have** to respect the cancellation token. You **cannot** simply stop task (like you can do with thread), you **have** to add the logic to check the state of the token **inside** your methods producing the tasks.

Comment: @VMAtm How can i modify the methods to do it ?

Comment: @VMAtm - You can't simply stop a thread either. If you do you risk corrupting the run-time. They **only** time you should ever stop a thread is when you're trying to forcibly exit your app entirely.

Comment: Yes, I know, still the task and threads are done in different ways.

Answer (score 10):

`CancellationToken` is the right way to go.

Are you trying to control how many tasks run at once? That's what the TPL already does, and it does it well.

See this example starting many CPU intensive tasks, then cancels all of them after three seconds:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var delay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Select(i => Task.Run(() => SlowSqrt/*Async*/(i, delay, cts.Token), cts.Token)).ToArray();
    Thread.Sleep(3000);
    cts.Cancel();
}

public static double SlowSqrt(double arg, TimeSpan delay, CancellationToken token)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Calculating Sqrt({arg})...");
    var burnCpuTimeUntil = DateTime.Now + delay;
    while (DateTime.Now < burnCpuTimeUntil) token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    var result = Math.Sqrt(arg);
    Console.WriteLine($"Sqrt({arg}) is {result}.");
    return result;
}

public static async Task<double> SlowSqrtAsync(double arg, TimeSpan delay, CancellationToken token)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Calculating Sqrt({arg})...");
    await Task.Delay(delay, token);
    var result = Math.Sqrt(arg);
    Console.WriteLine($"Sqrt({arg}) is {result}.");
    return result;
}
```

The output of which is:

```
Calculating Sqrt(1)...
Calculating Sqrt(2)...
Calculating Sqrt(0)...
Calculating Sqrt(3)...
Sqrt(2) is 1.4142135623731.
Calculating Sqrt(4)...
Sqrt(0) is 0.
Calculating Sqrt(5)...
Sqrt(3) is 1.73205080756888.
Calculating Sqrt(6)...
Sqrt(1) is 1.
Calculating Sqrt(7)...
Sqrt(5) is 2.23606797749979.
Calculating Sqrt(8)...
Sqrt(4) is 2.
Calculating Sqrt(9)...
Sqrt(6) is 2.44948974278318.
Calculating Sqrt(10)...
Sqrt(7) is 2.64575131106459.
Calculating Sqrt(11)...
```

As I have four cores on my machine, there are only 4 tasks being active at a time. Tasks that haven't started when the token is canceled (12..99) never even get kicked off. Tasks that are started (8..11) error out in `token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()`. All of them end in the `TaskStatus.Canceled` state.

Now if you change above code to invoke `SlowSqrtAsync`, the 1 second delay does not use the CPU, thus the TPL activates all 100 tasks, trying to max CPU usage. You get all 100 results after roughly one second. If you canceled a task while it is inside the `Task.Delay`, it would throw the `OperationCanceledException` just as `Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` would do.

```
Calculating Sqrt(0)...
Calculating Sqrt(1)...
:
:
Calculating Sqrt(92)...
Calculating Sqrt(89)...
(about 1 second later:)
Sqrt(19) is 4.35889894354067.
Sqrt(5) is 2.23606797749979.
:
:
Sqrt(99) is 9.9498743710662.
Sqrt(92) is 9.59166304662544.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer... in my case,what is the best way to cancel the tasks?

Comment: @techno - You haven't shown what your tasks are doing so we can't say how it is best to stop them. Keep in mind that you can't just clobber your task from another task or thread. You have to make your code in the task exit cleanly. The cancelation token is used to communicate to the running task so that it can shut itself down.

Comment: @Enigmativity How can i modify my method to check for the cancellation token?

Comment: Inside the method, either `token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` or check `token.IsCancellationRequested`. The former throws an `OperationCanceledException` with its `.CancellationToken` set to the token in question. If the task was started with this token, TPL will set the task's status to `TaskStatus.Canceled` rather than `TaskStatus.TaskStatus.Faulted`.

Comment: @techno - You need to show us what you're doing inside the tasks that you're trying to cancel for us to be able to say how to do it. Otherwise tindu's comment above is an excellent start for you.

Answer (score 0):

To stop multiple ongoing tasks, you can use `await Task.WhenAll(...)`, passing in an array of Tasks. Each tasks gets a reference to a `CancellationToken` (System.Threading). It's up to each task to (as they are doing their own work) check the token every now and then to see if cancellation has been requested - if so, and cancelling is ok, throw a `OperationCanceledException` - which the awaiting thread will catch accordingly.

Furthermore, but not neccessary to cancel, if you want to report progress from each task back to the awaiting thread, you can pass in a System.IProgress.

See working demo below using `CancellationToken` and `IProgress` (.NET 4.5.2 console app).

Happy coding.

```
private static CancellationTokenSource _tokenSource;
private static Progress<string> _progress = new Progress<string>((msg) => Console.WriteLine(msg));
private static IProgress<string> _progressReporter = _progress as IProgress<string>;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
  Task.Run(async () => await Run()).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}

private static async Task Run()
{
  try
  {
    Console.CancelKeyPress += Console_CancelKeyPress;

    using (_tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource())
    {
      _progressReporter.Report("Running 3 async tasks... press [Ctrl+C] to cancel.\r\n");

      await Task.WhenAll
      (
          DoWorkAsync(1, 6, _tokenSource.Token, _progress),
          DoWorkAsync(2, 3, _tokenSource.Token, _progress),
          DoWorkAsync(3, 4, _tokenSource.Token, _progress)
      );

      _progressReporter.Report($"\r\nRun complete: All tasks finished successfully (without user cancelling)");
    }
  }
  catch (OperationCanceledException)
  {
    _progressReporter.Report($"\r\nRun complete: User cancelled one or more ongoing tasks");
  }
  finally
  {
    Console.ReadLine(); // pause
  }
}

private static void Console_CancelKeyPress(object sender, ConsoleCancelEventArgs e)
{
  _progressReporter.Report("\r\nCancelling tasks...\r\n");
  _tokenSource.Cancel();
  e.Cancel = true;
}

private static async Task DoWorkAsync(int taskNumber, int durationInSeconds, CancellationToken ct, IProgress<string> progress)
{
  await Task.Run(() => 
  {
    if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
      progress.Report($"Task {taskNumber} cancelled before it started");
      return;
    }
    else
      progress.Report($"Started task {taskNumber} (duration: {durationInSeconds} sec. steps)");

    for (int i = 0; i < durationInSeconds; i++)
    {
      progress.Report($"Task {taskNumber} is working (on step {i + 1}/{durationInSeconds})");

      Thread.Sleep(1000); // simulate work in 1 sec steps

      if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
      {
        progress.Report($"Task {taskNumber} cancelled (upon request) after it started (on step {i + 1}/{durationInSeconds})");
        ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
      }
    }

    progress.Report($"Finished task {taskNumber}");
  });
}
```